# Unexpected Identifier Syntax Error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, syntax-error

I get an Unxepected Identifier editor with the following code.  I've been troubleshooting it all day, and nothing.  Hoping a fresh pair of eyes can spot my error.  I'm trying to use jQuery UI to set up a date-picker and then get and manipulate the date.  Changing the date on the picker should change an image on the page associated with that date via ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Datepicker
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    inline: true,
    minDate: new Date(2012, 06 - 1, 1),
    maxDate:new Date(2012, 09 - 1, 31),
    onSelect: function(){
       var day1 = ($("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getDate()).toString().replace(/(^.$)/,"0$1");              
       var month1 = ($("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getMonth() + 1).toString().replace(/(^.$)/,"0$1");             
        var year1 = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getFullYear();
        var fullDate = year1 + "/" + month1 + "/" + day1;
        var dashDate = year1 + "-" + month1 + "-" + day1;
        var str_output = "<a id=\"single_image\" href=\"http://www.lasalle.edu/150/dayinhistory/" + fullDate + ".jpg\" title=\"\"><img src=\"http://www.lasalle.edu/scripts/timthumb/timthumb.php?src=http://www.lasalle.edu/150/dayinhistory/" + fullDate + ".jpg&w=560&h=350&zc=1&a=t\">";
        $('#this-day-photo-archive').html(str_output);
        var data = 'day=' + dashDate;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://www.lasalle.edu/150/content/day_grab.php',
                type: "GET", 
                data: data,     
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $('#this-day-info').html(html);
                    console.log (html);
                    $(".left").click(function() {
                        $('#datepicker').datepicker( "setDate" , -1d );
                    });
                    $(".right").click(function() {
                        $('#datepicker').datepicker( "setDate" , +1d );
                    });
                }
            });
    } 

});

});
```

Comment: And **where** is the error ?

Comment: Good question.  I thought that maybe I was missing an operator or something.  Here is what Chrome says:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:2
e.extend.globalEval jquery.min.js:2
br jquery.min.js:2
e.extend.each jquery.min.js:2
f.fn.extend.domManip jquery.min.js:4
f.fn.extend.append jquery.min.js:3
f.fn.extend.html jquery.min.js:4
$.ajax.success 150ajax.js:167
n jquery.min.js:2
o.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
w jquery.min.js:4
d

Taking out the code block makes the error go away.

Comment: Not your error but you could use `data:{day:dashDate}`, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should replace

```
 $('#datepicker').datepicker( "setDate" , -1d );
```

with

```
 $('#datepicker').datepicker( "setDate" , "-1d" );
```

(and the same for `+1d`)

[A link to some examples for confirmation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#entry-examples)

Comment: The same happens 3 lines later again.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't flood here but I'm always happy when I receive an uppercase *"thank you!"* :D

Comment: I shouldn't either, but if I could reach through and give you a hug, I would.